# RandomNumberGenerator vs Aes generate key. Which should I use to get myself a key when using AES encryption (C#)

Tags: c#, encryption, random, aes

So I was checking some implementations online and I noticed that some people use the following way to generate a key:

```
        using (var random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            var key = new byte[32];
            random.GetBytes(key);
        }
```

While others use the generateKey method which is built in the AES class:

```
        using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
        {
            myAes.GenerateKey();
            var key = myAes.Key;
        }
```

Both of them are in the System.Security.Cryptography library, just wondering if there is an actual difference between them and if yes which one should I go with?

Comment: The whole reason `SymmetricAlgorithm.GenerateKey` exists is to abstract away from things like key sizes, which the first sample happily reintroduces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both versions do the same thing. `Aes.GenerateKey` will use the same `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` as first example to generate new key.

However I'd prefer to use second version, because:

1) It expresses intent very clear. You are generating AES key, not just arbitrary random byte array.

2) AES can have different key sizes. Not only that, but some key sizes are invalid for AES. First example now generates 32-byte keys only. If you modify it to accept key size - someone can pass invalid (for AES) key size to it. So you will need to validate passed size to verify it's a valid key size for AES. But why do that if `Aes` class already does that for you?

Side note: there is no need to call `GenerateKey`, though it does not harm too. If there is no key yet - it will be generated when you first access `Key` property.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  Both use the same underlying CSPRNG.  The results are equally secure.

You can view this in the [.NET Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com)

Comment: I would still prefer the second. If one day it is discovered that some classes of keys are "weak", the second implementation could probably be corrected by Microsoft to discard "weak" keys, while the first one  couldn't.